# Enumerator value evaluates to -2147483648, which cannot be narrowed to type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums, long-integer, unsigned

I have a enum which left shift `1 << type` for every type, but today I added a new type that is `31 << atype`, unfortunately, Xcode has given me the error

> Enumerator value evaluates to -2147483648, which cannot be narrowed to type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

[image]

It says the value is exceeded the maximum of `unsigned long` value. I wonder  I have never ever stumbled across this situation.

Why will it happen? How should I solve it?

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because literal constant `1` is of NSInteger type which means first byte decides signess of value. All you need to do is cast it to NSUInteger, so:

```
(NSUInteger)1 << 31
```